# table optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using **MySQl** , I have a table named **cars** which is in my **dev_db** database.

I inserted about **6,000,000** data into the table (That's a large amount of data insertion) by using **bulk insertion** like following:

```
INSERT INTO cars (cid, name, msg, date) 
VALUES (1, 'blabla', 'blabla', '2001-01-08'),
       (11, 'blabla', 'blabla', '2001-11-28'), 
       ... ,
       (3, 'blabla', 'blabla', '2010-06-03');
```

After this large data insertion into my **cars** table

I decide to also **optimize the table** like following:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE cars;
```

I waited 53min for the optimization, finally it is done and mysql console shows me the following message:

[image]

The `Msg_text` shows me **this table does not support optimize...** , which makes my brain yields **two questions to ask** :

**1.** Does the mysql message above means the 53min I waited actually did nothing useful??

**2.** is it necessary to optimize my table after large amount data insertion? and why?

Comment: just like @Topener says, if you want to optimize, create the needed indexes :)

Comment: And probably You could drop keys of Your tables before the optimization, and redefine it later, as Peter Zaitsev shown in his blog http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/12/09/thinking-about-running-optimize-on-your-innodb-table-stop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimize is useful if you have removed or overwritten rows, or if you have changed indexes. If you just inserted data it is not needed to optimize.

> The MySQL Optimize Table command will effectively de-fragment a mysql
>   table and is very useful for tables which are frequently updated
>   and/or deleted.

Also look here: http://www.dbtuna.com/article.php?id=15

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, You have InnoDB table, [which doesn't support OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html)

Comment: P.S. Found another similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816044/optimize-innodb-table

Comment: In the link you supply it says that InnoDB supports optimize table. Further down it says it is mapped on alter table and it shows the output Mellon got. So your answer is helpful but in this short form is not quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the output InnoDB does not support `optimize` as such.
Instead it does a `recreate` + `optimize` on the indexes instead.

The result is much the same and should not really bother you, you end up with optimized indexes.

However you only ever have to optimize your indexes **if** you delete rows or update indexed fields.
If you only ever insert then your B-trees will not get unbalanced and do not need optimization.

So:

> Does the mysql message above means the 53min I waited actually did nothing useful??

The time spend waiting was useless, but not for the reason you think.
If there is anything to optimize, MySQL will do it.

> is it necessary to optimize my table after large amount data insertion? and why?

No, never.
The reason is that MySQL (InnoDB) uses B-trees, which are fast only if they are balanced.
If the nodes are all on one side of the tree, the index degrades into a ordered list, which gives you O(n) worst case time, An fully balanced tree has O(log n) time.
However the index can only become unbalanced if you delete rows, or alter the values of indexed fields.